# How does the retina display affect the size of the underlying bitmap of an UIView?

Tags: iphone, uikit, retina-display

With the retina display, does a UIView with a frame of 100/100 points actually have a bitmap of 200/200 pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Memory-wise it's **x 4**.

Comment: So when I say I want a font with 20 px height, I actually get one with 40 height?

Comment: @openfrog - You don't specify fonts in terms of pixels, but points.  On old iPhones 1 point = 1 pixel, but on the Retina display 1 point = 2 pixels.  For future displays, this scaling may change to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you read the part of the iOS App Programming Guide [dealing with resolution independence](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW1).